searching a repost (retweet) from someone by content in the original X (tweet) - X / Twitter
I want to search all reposts (retweets) by @naval
where the original post (tweet) contained the word meditat*
here, the * is a wildcard so that various endings are possible.
Is it possible to do that in X's (Twitter's) advanced search or via a custom search string?
(Context: I remember reading a repost from @naval where the original X, by a different author, said something like: "you're not supposed to keep meditating forever. you go to the doctor to be cured, not to keep going back". I want to read that original X again because it was interestingly worded.)
